# Why should the sum of three numbers be even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, parity

It says in "104 Number Theory Problems" by Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, Zuming Feng
(October 25, 2006) in the solution to this problem

> Example 1.6. Find all positive integers n for which 3n − 4, 4n − 5, and 5n − 3
>   are all prime numbers.
>
> Solution: The sum of the three numbers is an even number, so at least one of
>   them is even. The only even prime number is 2. Only 3n − 4 and 5n − 3 can be
>   even. Solving the equations 3n − 4 = 2 and 5n − 3 = 2 yields n = 2 and n = 1,
>   respectively. It is trivial to check that n = 2 does make all three given numbers
>   prime.

My question is how do they figure out, just from the information given in the question, that the sum of these numbers be even?

Answer (score 4):

Because $3n-4+4n-5+5n-3=12n-12$, which is even.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the sum: $(3n-4)+(4n-5)+(5n-3)=n(3+4+5)-(3+4+5)=(n-1)(3+4+5)=12(n-1)$

and this is even